# LP Duals and Reduced Costs with CPLEX

Tags: linear-programming, cplex

I am working on a Column Generation algorithm using CPLEX to solve the Reduced Master Problem.

After adding the new variables to the RMP, I set their upper bounds to 0, solve the RMP again and retrieve their reduced costs (to check if the value I calculated matches the one provided by CPLEX).

In the first iterations, the reduced costs match.

However, after some iterations, I start getting different reduced cost.

When I run CPLEX Interative Optimizer, read the LP model (or MPS) and compare the duals of the constraints, I get some different values.

Does it make any sense?

I've tried using different methods for solving my LP. Also tried changing tolerances.

Problem stats

```
Objective sense      : Minimize
Variables            :  453308  [Fix: 8,  Box: 453300]
Objective nonzeros   :    6545
Linear constraints   :  578166  [Less: 70814,  Greater: 503886,  Equal: 3466]
  Nonzeros           : 2710194
  RHS nonzeros       :    7986

Variables            : Min LB: 0.0000000        Max UB: 74868.86
Objective nonzeros   : Min   : 0.01000000       Max   : 10000.00
Linear constraints   :
  Nonzeros           : Min   : 0.004000000      Max   : 396.8800
  RHS nonzeros       : Min   : 0.01250000       Max   : 74868.86
```

Displaying the solution quality I get these info:

```
Max. unscaled (scaled) bound infeas.        = 8.52651e-014 (3.33067e-015)
Max. unscaled (scaled) reduced-cost infeas. = 2.24935e-010 (5.62339e-011)
Max. unscaled (scaled) Ax-b resid.          = 5.90461e-011 (3.69038e-012)
Max. unscaled (scaled) c-B'pi resid.        = 2.6489e-011 (7.27596e-012)
Max. unscaled (scaled) |x|                  = 45433 (2839.56)
Max. unscaled (scaled) |slack|              = 4970.49 (80.1926)
Max. unscaled (scaled) |pi|                 = 295000 (206312)
Max. unscaled (scaled) |red-cost|           = 411845 (330962)
Condition number of scaled basis            = 1.1e+008
```

Comment: Could just be degeneracy. Duals and reduced cost are often not unique.

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned in the comment by Erwin, what you are experiencing is probably degeneracy.

Both the primal and dual solutions are often not unique in problems larger than a toy model.

By fixing a set of primal variables to their optimal level, assuming the solution was otherwise primal-dual optimal and the solution is stored in CPLEX, then it should take zero iterations reoptimizing the model after applying the fixes. Hence it should return the same solution. But if no solution is stored in CPLEX and you reoptimize from scratch, then CPLEX may return a different (but also optimal) (primal and/or dual) solution.

Do you see iterations in the log ?

As debug, try to write out the model before fixing and after, then do a diff on these two files to make sure there's not a modeling/programming mistake on your side.

You are also welcome to contact me at bo.jensen (at) dk (dot) ibm (dot) com and I will try to help you as I don't follow stack overflow closely.

Answer (score 3):

My guess would be that when you are setting up the subproblem you fail to account for the reduced cost of variables out of basis at their upper bound. Those reduced costs are essentially the dual values of the upper bound constraint and hence must be taken into account when setting up the subproblem.

This sort of accidental omission typically happens when the generated variables are created with an upper bound.

If really this is your problem, then the your easiest solution may be simply not specifying upper bounds for the new variables, which you can do if the upper bound is implied (e.g., from the new variable being part of a clique constraint).